Is there a way to find out which process is writing to a file on a server with restricted permissions?
Let's say I have a file named "app.log" and I want to find out which process is writing the log, but I have restricted permissions, I have tried the following:

lsof /path/to/file, which I dont' have this package and don't have the permission to install it.
loggedfs -l /path/to/log_file -c /path/to/config.xml /path/to/directory tail -f /path/to/log_file, same as the first one, don't have the permission to install this package.
auditctl -w /path/to/file, have this package but missing root permissions to run it.

what would be an alternative way to find out which process is writing the log to a file?
I'm looking for alternative ways because I'm working in an old production environment with some restricting and weird privileges.

You could try to tell us about the log file, maybe someone uses their human experience to recognize it :)

also, you could just run a locally-built lsof; no need to install it. Note that as non-root user, you have, no matter what you do very limited insight into what processes that are running as other users are doing. That's a very inherent security feature.

I’m voting to close this question because OP is asking how to perform a privileged operation without privileges - i.e. not possible.

@symcbean I'm not aware of the fact that this is a privileged operation, I'm looking for alternative ways because I'm working in an old production environment with some restricting and weird privileges.

@Ilgar but it is a privileged operation to learn about other user's processes' file handles. That's the thing. You need assistance from whoever has administrative privileges on that production system, no matter which software for analyzing the other users' processes you choose.

"old" is not an excuse for "not being in control". Someone should have root access - speak to them. If nobody has root access then you have a much serious problem than described here.

I completely understand the place you are talking from here, we have many apps running on a server which produce many log files, I wanted to see if there is a way to find out which processes are writing to them with my restricted privileges, and I understand this is not a clean way to do it and one should have the needed permissions to do this also if the question is not adhering to the community rules and needs to be closed I completely respect that, thank you.

this is not about a "clean way", this is about "absolutely no way, unless you find a very fundamental security flaw in the linux kernel, that nobody knows about so far" :) I don't think this needs to be closed, with the information given in your comments, we can write a (negative) answer.

If your process is operated as a service, the logfile might be mentioned in a config file. But best seems to be looking at the fle itself ....

Luckily, what you're trying to do is by principle a rather privileged operation: you're trying to look into other user's (UNIX meaning of the word "user") processes.
So, there's no alternative way, clean or not, to do that without the privileges you need. You'll have to ask someone who has the privileges to do so.
